# Proper way to create listboxitem with my data without databinding

Tags: .net, wpf

I need to create listbox with custom listboxitem's content. 
The main issue that i need to do this from code behind, i mean that i can't use databidning functionality(please don't ask about this :)).

So the idea that i have is create stackpanel and then assign it to Content property of created ListBoxItem. 
The problem i see - this stackpanel will have many other controls like buttons, labels, progress. So the code will look big and it will be hard to style it.

Is there a way to create xaml(describe styles and elements) for this datatemplate and after that use it in order to create fill and add new listboitem to listbox.

Comment: so why not just use the `XAML` directly? the benefit of using codebehind (instead of XAML) is to dynamically add new controls with dynamic options.

Comment: *Proper way to create listboxitem with my data without databinding*... what?? `DataBinding` *is* the proper way. With that in mind... 'I'm out'.

Comment: If you don't want to use data binding, it does not mean that you can't use XAML to build the UI. Just use it normally and remember to give your elements their own `Name` so you can refer to them in your code behind file.

Comment: A DataTemplate without data binding doesn't make sense. You could alternatively create a UserControl to visualize your items, and use that for the `Content` of the ListBoxItems. The UserControl might have dependency properties that present your data, and their property changed callbacks might set the UI elements in the UserControl, thus avoiding binding in the UserControl itself.

Comment: @Sheridan some times you need to stick rules which already exists in app so this is the reason. And i knew that there will be guys who ask me about this like you. May be i didn't explain it in right way(i havn't much exp in WPF) but what i need is to create template for this and not use Binding.

Comment: Almost what you can do in XAML, you can still do it using code behind. There is no reason not to use Binding. Note that you can use Binding using code behind (of course it may be not intuitive like in XAML code).

Comment: @AntonyBlazer sorry, this is ridiculous. What you are trying to do goes against **all** well known and established good practices and patterns in WPF, and you will **FAIL**. Procedurally creating UI elements in WPF breaks UI virtualization which, if your list has many items, will completely cripple your UI's performance to the point of being unusable. Not to mention all the horrible code behind practices you're seeking to use are completely unmaintainable and force you to introduce a LOT of unneeded code. Learn the proper way to work with WPF instead of insisting in this crap.

Answer (score 0):

You can define ControlTemplate for ListBoxItem.

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" TargetType="ListBoxItem">            
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Border>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>                        
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox>
        <ListBoxItem>Item1</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item2</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item3</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item4</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item5</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a XAML file for your StackPanel, setting its x:Class="MyNamespace.MyStackPanel", then define your public partial class MyStackPanel as needed and use instances of it either in code or from XAML